# Calendar V3 Broke and I have no idea why

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-calendar-api

I'm using the following code and it worked but all of a sudden it is not working. I have another method that gets free busy using the same auth and everything is working fine. Below is my method as well as the console log.

```
def createEvent(title, event_description, mentor, mentee, start_time, end_time)
    calendar_api = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
    calendar_api.authorization = @auth
    event = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event.new(
      summary: title,
      description: event_description,
      start: {
        date_time: start_time.iso8601,
        time_zone: 'Etc/UTC',
      },
      end: {
        date_time: end_time.iso8601,
        time_zone: 'Etc/UTC',
      },
      attendees: [
        {email: mentor},
        {email: mentee},
      ],
      reminders: {
        use_default: true,
      },
    )
    calendar_api.insert_event('primary', event)

  end
```

The console error I am getting is as shown

```
Sending HTTP post https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?
400
#<Hurley::Response POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events == 400 (276 bytes) 300ms>
Caught error invalid
Error - #<Google::Apis::ClientError: invalid>
```

Answer (score 0):

As suggested [here](https://github.com/trailblazer/representable/issues/171), try putting a breakpoint in a debug session to know  where the error was coming from. Also, the warning will be solved if you upgrade to 3.0 or turn off deprecations using `Representable.deprecations = false`. You may also check these references: https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/issues/407 and https://github.com/trailblazer/representable/issues/195

Comment: Still not luck other than providing a different error message as shown above.